# How to capture button action into javascript on ios?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, webview

I added html page on webview. I want to capture button action when I click the button. These are my javascript codes;

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Hide Bottom Menu" onClick="hideBottomMenu(true)" />
</div>
<script language="javascript">
        function hideBottomMenu(isHide){
            Bridge.hideBottomMenu(isHide);
        }
</script>
```

These are my objective-c codes;

I called html page on viewdidload, there is no problem to see html page.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bridge" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

UIWebView delegate methods;

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"hideBottomMenu()"];
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    return YES;
}
```

When I click the button on webview, UIWebview delegate method (shouldStartLoadWithRequest) not calling.I want to capture button action from there.

Can anybody help me? Thank you, Halil.

Answer (score 2):

you can find something useful helpful here http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html

but for this you would need to use wkwebview