# iOS - How does Cordova invoke objective c function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

How does cordova trigger objective-c native method. For example- When a user taps on submit button (html button), app needs to invoke native objective c function called 'dataSubmitted'.

- Does Cordova monitor webview navigation and based on URL tags call method internally?
- Is there any way JavaScript can interact with Obj-c native methods except monitoring webview navigations?

Comment: Cordova does monitor your navigation to call native methods.Other way of communication is using WKWebview.Check answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156280/how-to-capture-button-action-into-javascript-on-ios/37156704#37156704

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to communicate with native language from JS.
1. Go to MainViewController.m -> find a function named webViewDidFinishLoad
and add the follwing code snippet..

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    NSString *pageUrl = [theWebView.request.URL absoluteString];

    if ([pageUrl  containsString:@"xyz"]) {
      //   xyz for xyz.html
    }else if ([pageUrl  containsString:@"abc"]) {
      //  abc for abc.html
    }

    self.webView = theWebView;
    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

2. Develop your own native plugin with cordova.exec ;

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries available to communicate between Javascript and Objective-C it seems:

> WebViewJavascriptBridge: https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge
>
> GAJavaScript: https://github.com/newyankeecodeshop/GAJavaScript

I suggest you to check out this beautiful [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge) which explains Javascript & Objective-C interactions in detail.